# Remove attributes globally in all actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing a filter to universally remove the authorization attribute from all action methods within my application. Specifically, I'm focusing on the "ScopesAndPolicyAuthorize" attribute. Rather than individually modifying each custom "ScopesAndPolicyAuthorizeAttribute" to bypass authentication, I'm taking this approach to ensure consistency across various services. This way, the required changes can be applied more broadly and efficiently.

I have the filter index, but when the .RemoveAt happens I get a

```
System.NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size.\r\n   at System.SZArrayHelper.RemoveAt[T](Int32 index)
```

Filter code

```
public class RemoveAuthAttributes : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var scopeAndPolicyAttributeIndex = context.Filters
            .ToList()
            .FindIndex(x => x.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName.Contains("ScopesAndPolicyAuthorize"));

        context.Filters.RemoveAt(scopeAndPolicyAttributeIndex);
    }
}
```

Pipeline code

```cs
.AddMvc(options => { 
 if (isDev) {
   options.Filters.Add(new RemoveAuthAttributes());
 }
})
```

Comment: I think what you should do is marking the endpoints  as allowanoymous  rather  than removing the Authorize Attibute  to Avoid Aothorization...